# GO: how can i use go reflect to set the value of pointer of struct

Tags: go, reflect

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Config struct {
    App *AppConfig
}

type AppConfig struct {
    Name string
}

func (a *AppConfig) Parse() {
    a.Name = "111"
}

var (
    config = &Config{
        App: &AppConfig{},
    }
)

func main() {

    v := reflect.ValueOf(*config)
    typeOf := reflect.TypeOf(*config)

    for i := 0; i < typeOf.NumField(); i++ {
        method := v.Field(i).MethodByName("Parse")
        method.Call([]reflect.Value{})
    }
    fmt.Println(config)
}
```

look at this, it can run successfully

but when i change

```
var (
    config = &Config{
        App: &AppConfig{},
    }
)
```

to

```
var (
    config = &Config{}
)
```

it will be failed with error #*panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference*#

how can i run successfully with

```
var (
    config = &Config{}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `f := v.Field(i)` where `f` represents a pointer type, you first need to check whether the value represented by `f` isn't `nil`, there's a method for that in the reflect package. And if you get back `true`, i.e. it *is* `nil`, then, before you can call a method on that field, you need to initialize that field so that is it not `nil` anymore. i.e. `f.Set(reflect.New(f.Type().Elem()))`.

And you also need to make sure that the `f` is *addressable*, to do that, pass a pointer to the config to reflect, i.e. `*Config`, not `Config`.

```golang
v := reflect.ValueOf(config).Elem()
typeOf := reflect.TypeOf(config).Elem()

for i := 0; i < typeOf.NumField(); i++ {
    f := v.Field(i)
    if f.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && f.IsNil() {
        f.Set(reflect.New(f.Type().Elem()))
    }
    method := f.MethodByName("Parse")
    method.Call([]reflect.Value{})
}
fmt.Println(config)
fmt.Println(config.App)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/DMRFS41NXFS